# direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D.ucode failed with error -2

Tags: drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I am trying to fix the wifi in my Intel NUC. I have the `Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210`. The driver is trying to load 'iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode` but according to dmesg, that fails with error -2 (see below).

System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux britt-desktop 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dmesg | grep 7265D
[   14.578598] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.578612] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2



$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode
```

Any idea how to get the correct firmware to load? Thank you

EDIT:

I found a copy of iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode and moved it to /lib/firmware. The errors are gone, but my wifi performance is still very low (~1/10th what the other older machines on the network are getting).

EDIT:

I have a ASUS RT-AC68W wireless router and I am using the 5GHz band. After I changed the wireless mode to N/AC mixed (it was on Auto), the download speeds went back up to >100Mbps. I'll keep an eye on it, but this may have fixed it. I also and using firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode for now as 24 and 23 are not in the directories.

```
sudo wget https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/raw/master/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. My wifi freezes up randomly and I haven't been able to figure it out. I was hoping a firmware upgrade would fix it but apparently it's not happening.

Comment: what is the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`? I think I solved my issue by finding iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode and adding it to /lib/firmware. It wasn't on intel's page though.

Comment: I have the same error too on Ubuntu 16.10 (update from 16.04) on an ASUS UX305 with Intel 7265D wifi card.. Where did you find the missing ucode files?

Comment: Here's a gist of my `dmesg` output: https://gist.github.com/adamcrown/4bd9481d4f8039d9aedce06d75948064

I'm guessing the real problem is `Microcode SW error detected`. My issue seems to be only a problem with my router. So I may just take the easy way out and get a new one.

Comment: I searched google for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode and moved that the /lib/firmware

Comment: Same problem with Asus UX303UB. On [kernel wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#and_7265_support) say _7260 and 7265 will not be supported by the newest firmware versions: the last firmware that was released for these devices is -17.ucode_ .

Comment: @PabloBianchi This page also notes that this doesn't apply to the D versions, which are supported by newer versions. And this question is about a D version.

Comment: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep iwlwifi `shows that the driver is already loaded.

Comment: same here, and not searching towards because of this: [Wireless Networking Forum - Intel® Community Forum](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490XMsSAM/help-find-drivers-iwlwifi7265d2325?language=en_US)